# Use value returned from main dataset in sub dataset of iReport

Tags: jasper-reports, subreport

I have created a report with `Jaspersoft Studio 6.4.3.final` which contains `List Element`. I need to use value returned from main dataset in sub dataset (List Element) query.

Main data set return something like below. (always only one record return)

```
CustomerName     JobID
John             123,146
```

I need to use `JobID` in sub dataset (List Element) query as below.

```
Select * from JOB where jobId in (123,146)
```

I need to use the `123,146` form value returned from main dataset.

How could I achieve this?

**What I have tried**

I have created a parameter in sub report as below.
[image: param_details]

Then bound the relevant field from main report to the sub report parameter as below.
[image]

Updated the sub dataset query as

```
Select * from JOB where $X{IN,jobId,p_jobId}
```

With these changes, I am getting below exception.

> Invalid type java.lang.String for parameter p_jobId used in an IN
> clause; the value must be an array or a collection.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the value returned from the main dataset as a parameter to the List element and use it in the subdataset.

If it's a multi value parameter, you can use the $X notation in the subdataset query.

So your query could look something like this:

`Select * from JOB where $X{IN, jobId, MyParam}`

Where MyParam is the subdataset parameter name.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have tried something similar to this. But how to bind main dataset value to  subdataset parameter? Create a parameter as `MyParam` in subdataset and use it as ` $X{IN, jobId, MyParam}` will just enough?

Comment: You can pass the value from the main dataset to the subdataset through the List element.

Here's an example for how you would do that with a Table - https://community.jaspersoft.com/questions/823038/passing-main-parameter-sub-datasets-jasperstudio.

It would be very similar with a List as well.

Comment: Got some issues. Could you please check the updated question for more details.